# Save the state of button in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm disabling buttons once they are pressed. I want it to activate automatically 
the next day at 12AM. I really have no idea how to do this. Somehow I tried and written the code below.

The code disables the buttons after a click. But it is looses his state once the app is closed. Please help me how can I do this?

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        Button button1;
        Button button2;



        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            mybroadcast myrec = new mybroadcast ();
            Database sqldb1 = ((GlobalClass)this.Application).sqldb;//This will contain "Hello World"
            string stringFromApplicationClass = ((GlobalClass)this.Application).myString;//This will contain "Hello World"
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            string dataFormatada = string.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000}", now.Month, now.Day, now.Year);
            string currentTime = (string.Format ("Current Time: {0}", now.Hour));
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.Button1);
            button2 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.Button2);


            button1.Click += delegate {
                sqldb1.AddRecord (1);

            };


            button2.Click += delegate {

                sqldb1.AddRecord (0);
            };
        }


        public void start()
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent (this,typeof( mybroadcast)); 

            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            Calendar calendar =  Calendar.GetInstance (Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

            calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 12);
            calendar.Set(CalendarField.Millisecond, 00);
            calendar.Set(CalendarField.Second, 00);
            alarmMgr.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc,0, 10, pendingIntent); //Repeat every 24 hours

        }



        public class mybroadcast:BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent myIntent)
            {
                ((MainActivity)context).enablebutton();
            }
        }
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);

            MenuInflater inflater = this.MenuInflater;

            inflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.items, menu);

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
        {
            base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);

            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
            case Resource.Id.week:
                StartActivity(typeof(SecondActivity));
                break;
            case Resource.Id.month:
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof(ThirdActivity));
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
            }

            return true;

        }



        public void disablebutton()
        {

            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }


        public void enablebutton()
        {

            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using AlarmManager? Use it to schedule the button enable state at a specific time. Link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: i m not able to do in xamarin please help me:(

Comment: You could save the disabled state in the Apps configuration and when you load the App the next day check the time if it's after 12 AM. If so you can enable the button otherwise set it to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this code is in java, the concept will be the same. Once the alarm goes off, the Broadcastreceiver's onReceive is called, where you can edit the sharedpreference to enable/disable views. If you don't know about sharedpreferences, see these links: [How do I use SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android) , [SharedPreferences Example in Xamarin Android](http://javatechig.com/xamarin/sharedpreferences-example-in-xamarin-android)

**BroadCastReceiver:**

```
public class ReminderActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Use sharepreference and set the button state disabled or enabled.
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    mSharedPreferences..edit().putBoolean("btn_enable", true).commit();

}
}
```

So once you open the app, check for sharedpreference value and enable or disable the button state accordingly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you i will try this today:)